# Connecting to an OpenShift MySQL database with Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, openshift

I just have a quick question to make sure that I'm doing everything right before proceeding with my web application.

I've written my web app in Eclipse and am hosting it through OpenShift. Using OpenShift, I've also set up a MySQL database (I had previously been using Derby for the local stuff, but I've decided to move to MySQL because OpenShift does not accommodate Derby).

I want to be able to 1) connect to the MySQL and create tables, etc. and 2) connect to the MySQL within my servlets. My question here primarily concerns the first order of business.

When I call port-forward, I get:

```
Service Local               OpenShift
------- -------------- ---- -----------------
java    127.0.0.1:8080  =>  127.11.150.1:8080
mysql   127.0.0.1:3306  =>  127.11.150.2:3306
```

Now, when I navigate to Database Development in Eclipse and go to create a new database, when type in:

```
jdbc:mysql://127.11.150.2:3306/<my-app-name>
```

... for the URL, along with my username and password (and where  is the name of my app), the ping fails. However, for:

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/<my-app-name>
```

Everything works just peachy.

My question is this: **if I use the local IP address, will my servlets still be able to access the database when Eclipse is shut down and the port-forward is closed?** If not, what do I need to do to edit and update the MySQL database through Eclipse?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ip-address you got from the openshift `ssh`-console (or from your OpenShift web profile, doesn't matter here) is a strictly local ip-address used for your application. You may probably deploy some `web`-admin interface (like `phpMyAdmin`) to communicate with your **OpenShift** database from outside, but that's not desirable for some security reasons. In a normal way your database is allowed for access only through other openshift artifacts.

Openshift, in turn, provides some predefined environment variables with databases urls and so forth. You could check them out in your ssh-console.

So, if you set the appropriate configuration (corresponing to the **OpenShift** database) at your OpenShift web-container then yes, it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply - I'm going to go ahead, with your comments in mind, and report back to see how things go.

Comment: @jpabene BTW, you're using JBoss 7.1.1 as the OpesShift web-container, aren't you?

Comment: I'm using Tomcat 7 here - should I migrate over to JBoss 7.1.1? WARNING: when it comes to web containers, there's a good chance I have no idea what I'm talking about haha!

Comment: @jpabene Of course not, you shouldn't. I just asked about that because I myself used JBoss 7.1.1 when started playing with openshift. You may consider migrating to the latest wildfly version if it's available there, but JBoss 7.1.1 is too old...

Comment: Quick clarification: in my servlet, when using DriveManager.getConnection to create my Connection, should I use the local address in the URL or the OpenShift address?

Comment: See, It's not a good way to configure a jdbc-connection, you couple your code to a specific url. That's not desirable because you going to have to change the code (database url at least) every time you deploy your application to OpenShift. The most common approach here is using Resources [read more there](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-mysql-datasource-in-tomcat-6/) . As I already said, you have to configure your __container__ correctly.